# Split a query with too many arguments in SQLAlchemy

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, asyncpg

In my program when I did not run a database update for a long time and then try to update my data,
my sqlalchemy script generates a postgresql upsert query with >4000 params each with >8 items.

When the query is executed with `databases.Database.execute(query)` I end up with this error:

```
asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError: the number of query arguments cannot exceed 32767
```

My idea is to automatically split the query based on the number of arguments as threshold and execute it in two parts and merge the results.

Do you have an idea how to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up writing a check for the number of query arguments by getting the length of the first argument's dictionary keys in my list of argument dictionaries as they all have the same number of keys=arguments per list item:

```
args_per_row = len(args_dict_list[0])

PSQL_QUERY_ALLOWED_MAX_ARGS = 32767

allowed_args_per_query = int(math.floor(PSQL_QUERY_ALLOWED_MAX_ARGS/args_per_row))
```

Then I divided the args_dict_list into parts that have the size of allowed args per query:

```
query_args_sets = [
    args_dict_list[x:x + allowed_args_per_query] for x in range(
        0,
        len(args_dict_list),
        allowed_args_per_query
    )
]
```

and finally looped over the query_args_sets and generated and executed a separate query for each set:

```
for arg_set in query_args_sets:
    query = query_builder.build_upsert(values=arg_set)
    await database.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 1):

A generalized function for @Basiti's answer. It uses `async/await`, but you can easily migrate it to the usual `sync` code.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert as insert_
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession


PSQL_QUERY_ALLOWED_MAX_ARGS = 32767


async def pg_bulk_insert(
        session: AsyncSession, table,
        data, statement_modifier=None,
        insert=insert_
):

    if statement_modifier is None:
        def statement_modifier(s):
            return s

    complete_batches = []

    current_batch = []
    current_count = 0
    for row in data:
        params_count = len(row)
        current_count += params_count
        if current_count >= PSQL_QUERY_ALLOWED_MAX_ARGS:
            complete_batches.append(current_batch)
            current_batch = [row]
            current_count = params_count
        else:
            current_batch.append(row)
    if len(current_batch) > 0:
        complete_batches.append(current_batch)

    for batch in complete_batches:
        statement = statement_modifier(
            insert(table)
            .values(batch)
        )
        await session.execute(statement)
```